# .NetCore code with sustainsys-saml2 does nothing

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I have an .Net MVC project with SSO working. The SSO config looks like this:

```
    <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
      <caches>
        <sessionSecurityTokenCache type="Vixion.IdentityModel.Cache.SharedSessionSecurityTokenCache, Vixion.IdentityModel.Cache">
          <cacheServiceAddress url="http://tvwapps35434d.kpnis.nl:1008/SessionSecurityTokenCacheService.svc" />
        </sessionSecurityTokenCache>
      </caches>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="http://localhost:24442/" />
      </audienceUris>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="http://vix-make-o:8080">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="5137c779a1e77a0f4a78abd356b0238912637469" />
          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="http://vix-make-o:8080" />
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" path="/" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="http://vix-make-o:8080" realm="http://localhost:24442/" requireHttps="false" reply="http://localhost:24442/" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
```

According to the example here:
https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/tree/master/Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2

I write this code in a new .NetCore app:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()                
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
});

services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddSaml2(options =>
    {
        options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("http://vix-make-o:8080");
        options.IdentityProviders.Add(
            new IdentityProvider(
                new EntityId("http://vix-make-o:8080/ws_saml_metadata"), options.SPOptions)
            {
                //LoadMetadata = true
            });                    
    });

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseSession();
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

When I start the app, the browser goes straight to the index page. No error, no nothing. When I check with SAML Chrome Panel it shows no traffic at all.

I do not expect my code working, but it should at least do something to give me a hint to how to go further.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you.

S.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the web.config content. It is not used with the ASP.NET Core module.

Set back the LoadMetadata flag, or add the necessary config manually.

Set Saml2 as the default challenge protocol for authentication.

Finally, add an `[Authorize]` attribute to your controllers that should require authentication to initiate the authentication process.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but I know that I don't use the web.config in .NetCore. I just gave it for the working example.

Comment: When I set back the LoadMetadata flag the app crashes. I do not get back any metadata from this server.

Comment: If the server doesn't provide any metadata, you need to configure the required parameters manually on the IdentityProvider object: SsoServiceUrl, Binding and SigningCertificate.