# Set up SustainSys SAML2 with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sustainsys-saml2

I have an existing ASP.NET application and I want it to act as an SAML2 SP using SustainSys SAML2. The documentation says that I should use the web.config file but [it gets ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189131/netcore-code-with-sustainsys-saml2-does-nothing) on .NET Core.

So, **how do I start?**

I assume I should write a bit of code to my Startup class, but what and where? The thread linked above tells some things but I need more details. How do I set Saml2 as the default challenge protocol for authentication?

I added the code from the documentation (`services.AddAuthentication().AddSaml2(...);` in void ConfigureServices() and even `app.UseAuthorization();` in void Configure()) and when I try to add the `[Authorize]` attribute to a controller, I get an exception telling me "a middleware was not found that supports authorization. Configure your application startup by adding app.UseAuthorization() inside the call to Configure(..) in the application startup code."

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 package and add it in startup.

Web.config is not used on AspNet Core, you have to configure in startup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but could you add a bit further explanation?
If I shouldn't add and configure Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2, how do I do it?
Is there maybe a documentation for .NET Core?

Comment: Check the Sample AspNetCore2 application in the repo.